# Send data from server to another by curl or any other way

Tags: php, curl, remote-server

I have two servers. 
The first (Local) is the server which has the script.
The second (Remote) is the server which has uploaded files only (just for storage).

Now I'm confused about how to upload the files, and I have 2 ways and I don't know what the best one of them.

**The ways:**

1. Upload the file to the local server first and make all security
   operations like (check file size,file type, and so on), then upload
   again to the second server (remote server).
2. Upload the file to the second server (remote server) directly,
   and make all checks and security operations in there, then send the file information to the first server (local) to store the info into database.
3. Or there is another way is better than them ?

I have tried to apply the second way, by send the file directly to the second server (remote server) and then after everything is ok, the second server (remote server)  send to the first server (local) all information about the uploaded file by curl.

**For example:**
The following code written in file exists in php file in the second server (remote server).

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localServer/script/receiveReques.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('fileName' => 'filename.zip', 'size' => 1000, 'path'=> 'http://remoteserver.com/files/filenmae.zip'));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But the problem I don't know how to get the sent information.

**The summary  of my questions is:**

1. What the best way to do that ?
2. How to receive the file information from the second server (remote
   server) that has been sent by curl ?

Comment: When you say “local server”, what exactly does that mean? Is it reachable via HTTP under an address that is known to your other server?

Comment: @CBroe:
`local server(First)` = which has the installed script and database.
`remote server(Second)` = just to storage the files.   yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`

all you need to do is use the data it returns

`$data = curl_exec($ch);`

all of the data is now in `$data`

Comment: Sorry, but How to use the data in the first server(local) ? The scenario is, upload the file directly to the the second server (remote server), then when upload completed it (remote server) will send the file information to the first server. the previous code is written in php file and this file reside in the second server, How to receive the information was sent in the first server. (**I hope my idea to be clear**)